# How can kill the default behavior of kendo UI events

Tags: events, kendo-ui

What we can do, to kill the default behavior of an kendo events, like we do it in jquery events [ex: e.preventDefault].

Need: I am using kendo datepicker in that when user change any date the date picker is disappearing, but I don't want this behaviour[I want to stop this behavior].

What I have to write in "change" event handler to remove default behavior.